# Maven - Get non-inheritable pom version.

Tags: maven, inheritance, pom.xml

Assume a parent pom with version 1.0 and a child pom with version 2.0.

Now I define a dependency like this in the parent.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>somedep</groupId>
   <artifactId>somedep</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In the parent, the version evaluates to 1.0, but in child it evaluates to  2.0. Is there a way, in which I can make it evaluate to 1.0 in  child too (Ofcourse no version harcoding in parent is permitted)?

Comment: Why do you want to make your project's version the same as an external library's version? Or, vice versa, how do you think you can assure that an external library's version follows your project's version?

Comment: Actually this is not a 3rd party library. My project is actually a parent-pom with multiple modules. I want pom of one module to depend on pom of other sibling module.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

If we look in http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance, we can see that:

> One factor to note is that these variables are processed after
>   inheritance as outlined above. This means that if a parent project
>   uses a variable, then its definition in the child, not the parent,
>   will be the one eventually used.

Which means that you can't rely on variables which get dynamically resolved in parent and child and are of the type `${project.version} if your child and parent have different versions, which is generally not what you'd want but very specific to your case. I guess what you are left over with is to hardcode the dependency in the parent using something like depedencyManagement:

Parent:

```
<project>
   <groupId>example</artifactId>
   <artifactId>masta</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <dependencyManagement> 
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>someDep</groupId>
              <artifactId>someDep</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>someDep</groupId>
         <artifactId>someDep</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

And child:

```
<project>
   <parent>
      <groupId>example</artifactId>
      <artifactId>masta</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>example.masta</artifactId>
   <artifactId>child</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>someDep</groupId>
         <artifactId>someDep</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

or, indeed, use `${parent.version}` explicitly in the child. One thing to note is I'd generally not have aggregator projects like parent introduce any dependencies but have only dependencyManagement.

This is the second approach, without dependency management:

Parent:

```
  <project>
       <groupId>example</artifactId>
       <artifactId>masta</artifactId>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>someDep</groupId>
             <artifactId>someDep</artifactId>
             <version>${project.version}</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </project>
```

And child:

```
   <project>
       <parent>
          <groupId>example</artifactId>
          <artifactId>masta</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
       </parent>
       <groupId>example.masta</artifactId>
       <artifactId>child</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>someDep</groupId>
             <artifactId>someDep</artifactId>
             <version>${parent.version}</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </project>
```

But I guess none of the approaches actually fully satisfies what you want.

Comment: Hi baba, This example works, because you have hardcoded "1.0" as someDep version. Make it "${project.version}" and then you can see it is evaluated differently in parent and in child. Parent will use 1.0 but the child will use 2.0. The problem is because 'project.version' is a inheritable  and overridable variable.

Comment: Hi Baba, Your new example also does not work. It behaves the same as the old one.

Comment: @AshishTyagi you are right, it seems it does the inheritance before the interpolation, as can be noted here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance